# Multiple back buttons created when navigates to root screen in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

say I create 3 screens in SwiftUI which contains a NavigationLink to the next screen. like, first screen navigates to 2nd screen. 2nd screen navigates to third. and the third screen navigates to the first screen. In this case even if I use NavigationView only once(in the first screen). I encountered that there's a back button forming when I navigate to 1st screen from the third screen. And it keeps adding up when I start to navigate from then on. I have tried to use `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)`. It hides it but the space taken by back button was still there.
My code is similar to this:

```
struct FirstScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondScreen()) {
                    Text("Go to Second Screen")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: ThirdScreen()) {
                Text("Go to Third Screen")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ThirdScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: FirstScreen()) {
                Text("Go to First Screen")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[this is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkgHO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pushing the `FirstScreen` onto your navigation stack, but `FirstScreen` contains its own `NavigationView`. If you really want to keep pushing them on the stack, then move the `NavigationView` outside of `FirstScreen`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack { // Use NavigationStack for iOS 16
            FirstScreen()
        }
    }
}

struct FirstScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: SecondScreen()) {
                Text("Go to Second Screen")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you actually want to pop all the views off the stack and go back to `FirstScreen` you should use

```
init(path: Binding<NavigationPath>, etc)
```

---

Here's a simple example passing the `path` down the stack and resetting it to pop back to the root…

```
enum Screen {
    case two, three
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var path = NavigationPath()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            VStack {

                // value gets appended to path
                NavigationLink("Go to Second Screen", value: Screen.two)
            }

            // Decides which screen to show for values in path
            .navigationDestination(for: Screen.self) { index in
                switch index {
                case .two:
                    SecondScreen(path: $path)
                case .three:
                    ThirdScreen(path: $path)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondScreen: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink("Go to Third Screen", value: Screen.three)
        }
    }
}

struct ThirdScreen: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Go to First Screen") {

                // reset the path to pop to root
                path = NavigationPath()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanna go with this approach 
init(path: Binding<NavigationPath>, etc)
could you elaborate it in my context?

Comment: But it only supports for iOS 16. Do we have a solution which doesn't use NavigationPath?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswiftui%5D+pop+to+root

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you are using two navigation stacks in your SwiftUI app, which is causing two back buttons to appear when navigating between views.

To fix this issue, you can make sure that you are only using one navigation stack in your app. One way to do this is by using a single NavigationView for your entire app and then using NavigationLink to navigate between views.

Here's an example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) {
                    Text("Go to Second View")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("First View")
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Second View")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Second View")
    }
}
```